# Purple caterpillar found in Peru rainforest

Tags: species-identification

Caterpillar fron Peru rainforest with purple body and orange or reddish tips. From Manu National Park[image]

Comment: That's a very striking caterpillar. Unfortunately a lot of caterpillars in those regions haven't been matched to an adult butterfly, so it might be very difficult to get an answer.